# Selenium Webscraping for some reason data only brings back partial instead of everything. Not sure if any dynamic data is in background

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Python and Selenium beginner here. I'm trying to scrape the title of the sections of an Udemy class. I've tried using the find_elements_by_class_name and others but for some reason only brings back partial data.

page I'm scraping: https://www.udemy.com/selenium-webdriver-with-python3/

1) I want to get the title of the sections. They are the bold titles.

2) I want to get the title of the subsections.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.udemy.com/selenium-webdriver-with-python3/'

driver.get(url)

main_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("lecture-title-text")

sub_titles =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title")
```

Problem

1) Using main_titles, I got the length to be only 10. It only goes from  Introduction to Modules. Working With Files and ones after all don't come out. However, the class names are exactly the same. Not sure why it's not.  Modules / WorkingWithFiles is basically the cutoff point. The elements in the inspection also looks different at this point. They all have same span class tag but not sure why only partial is being returned

```
<span class="lecture-title-text">
```

[Element Inspection between Modules title and WorkingWithFiles title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmLwu.png)

At this point the webscrape breaks down. Not sure why.

2) Using sub_titles, I got length to be 58 items but when I print them out, I only get the top two:

```
Introduction
How to reach me anytime and ask questions? *** MUST WATCH ***
```

After this, it's all blank lines. Not sure why it's only pulling the top two and not the rest when all the tags have

```
<div class='title'>
```

Maybe I could try using BeautifulSoup but currently I'm trying to get better using Selenium. Is there a dynamic content throwing off the selenium scrape or am I not scraping it in a proper way?

Thank you guys for the input. Sorry for the long post. I wanted to make sure I describe the problem correctly.

Comment: Just a guess, but do you have it clicking the `24 More Sections` at the bottom of the `Curriculum For This Course` before trying to scrape the data?

Comment: For the sub_titles, you have to expand them all. Use some selenium function to loop and click them including those hidden '24 More Sections' before getting information from the class again.

Comment: And also, I'm afraid that, it's not working with solely BeautifulSoup in this case because its dynamic content that you have to interact with your browser (in this case, selenium) before you can parse HTML to any HTML parser library.

Comment: Ok I see what you guys are saying. So due to dynamic content (this one being me having to click that '24 more sections') and then scraping it. I will try this right now and let you guys know. Thank you so much

Comment: Ok. I did what you guys suggested by creating a object to click on the '24 more sections' to open the tab and scrape it. It worked perfectly! Thank you guys

Comment: @FonyLew That isn't needed. The method I described in my answer works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your only getting the first 10 sections is because only the first ten courses are shown. You might be logged in on your browser, so when you go to check it out, it shows every section. But for me and your scraper it's only showing the first 10. You'll need to click that `.section-container--more-sections` button before looking for the titles.

As for the weird case of the `title`s not being scraped properly: It's because when a element is hidden `text` attribute will always be undefined, which is why it only works for the first section. I'd try using the `WebElement.get_attribute('textContent')` to scrape the text.

Comment: I will try this method as well. Some commenters suggested clicking on the 'more' subsection object then scraping it. I'm going to try both methods and learn both. Thank you so much. Will let know how this turns out

Comment: Using your webelement.get_attribute('textContent') worked perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Ok I've went through the suggestions in the comments and have solved it. I'm writing it here in case anyone in future wants to see how solution went.

1) Using suggestions, I made a command to click on the '24 more sections' to expand the tab and then scrape it, which worked perfectly!

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-load-more").click()
titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("lecture-title-text")
for each in titles:
    print (each.text)
```

This pulled all 34 section titles.

2) Using Matt's suggestion, I found the WebElement and used get_attribute('textContent') to pull out the text data. There were bunch of spaces so I used split() to get strings only.

```
sub_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title")
for each in sub_titles:
    print (each.get_attribute('textContent').strip())
```

This pulled all 210 subsection titles!

Comment: why the downvote? is it because i added the result by adding as comment?